# Android emulator authorization dialog appear "always allow from this computer" everytime

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

When I use an Android emulator for the first time it needs authorization for USB debugging. But when I turn on the emulator the authorization dialog shows for about 300ms and then disappears, and this dialog won't be shown until I restart the emulator again. One time I started to click continuously on the place that I guessed the confirmation button of the dialog will be shown and that time the authorization was successful but I have to do this every time! As I don't have enough time to check "Always trust this computer" in that 300ms. I know it is a weird problem but please help if you have any suggestions.

I use the following software versions:

> android studio 3.2.1
> android emulator 28.0.20
> HAXM Installer 7.3.2
> virtual device android 9.0 (google play)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The weird thing is that it automatically authorizes when I wipe the emulator's user data, but it only works for that session before it forces me to reauthorize.

Comment: I only encounter this problem when emulating Android 9 Pie - download images for Android 8 or lower and the USB dialog should appear for longer. Hopefully Google will fix this bug in future versions of Android Pie.

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57478183/7429464

Comment: I have this problem too on big sur sdk 30

Comment: What's your emulator type (like Google Pixel 6, etc)?

Comment: @BentheCoder Pixel 2

Comment: @PayamRoozbahani Try using a different one, like the Pixel 6.  The Pixel 2 is (I think) much older and might be the cause of the glitch. I've used Pixel 6 emulators and they don't have the bug that you describe.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following methods to fix the issue,

**Method 1:**

- Go to the `.android` folder located in the root folder of your
  machine.

  > `~/.android/` in linux/mac and
  > `C:\Users\username\android` in windows

[image]

- Reset the Android ADB authentication key by **deleting `adbkey` and
  `adbkey.pub` files from the `.android` folder** and then restarting ADB. A
  new authentication key (pair) will be generated which will hopefully work.

**Method 2:**

- Change the power settings of your computer to reduce the processor
  state to 5%.
- Start the emulator with a cold boot.
- Spam the allow button when the "Allow USB Debugging" window pops up.

Answer (score 0):

Try wiping the data for the virtual device by going to Android Studio > "AVD Manager," then click the dropdown menu next to your virtual device and select "Wipe Data."